# Responsive elements stop shrinking and go off screen

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm making a Todo list and I'm having trouble with the CSS.

I have truncated the text for each item in the todo list using:

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
```

However, the list items div won't shrink its width after a certain point.
Its as if there is a min-width rule somewhere that's in effect. When I continue to shrink the browser window, the items go off screen to the right.

My desired result is to have the list item width shrink with the browser window until the browser cant get any narrower. 
also the text div should shrink and truncate with the div that contains it.

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 0%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

li button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.itemdiv {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #9DBDCF;
  text-indent: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  max-height: 55px;
  display: table;
}

.buttondiv {
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.text {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="listcontainer">
  <ul id="itemlist">
    <li>
        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="buttondiv">

          <button id="complete" class="complete"></button>
          <button id="remove" class="remove"></button>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your .itemdiv css specifies a min-width -- I think this div will prevent your list from becoming less wide.

Comment: I added min width for that because if I shrink the window any further the buttons start to stack on top of each other. Even when I remove that, it shrinks a little further but then it stops again and the item div goes off the screen. its like there's another min-width rule somewhere that I cant find.